# summing only the numbers contained in a list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Give a method that sums all the numbers in a `list`. The method should be able to   skip elements that are not numbers. So, `sum([1, 2, 3])` should be `6` but `sum(['A', 1, 'B', 2, 3])` *should also* be `6`. How can I accomplish this?

What I have already tried so far:

```
def foo(list):
    dict = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN"
    n = 0
    for i in range(0, len(list) - 1):
        if list[i].str in dict:
            ""
        else:    
            n= n + list[i]
    return n

print foo([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, "A", "B"])
```

Comment: Replace `list[i].str` with `str(list[i])`.

Comment: Sounds like homework to me.

Comment: @JonasGröger He posted the code he wrote I guess.

Comment: @Delgan I didn't see a error message or a unexpected result. He just pasted the code there.

Comment: its previous year exam papers, trying to solve. But unable to and yes the code is wrong so asking how to solve this type

Comment: Notes: avoid variable names like `dict` and `list` since they are the names of built-in functions. Your variable named `dict` is actually a string, not a dictionary. Perhaps a name like `letters` would be clearer.

Answer (score 19):

You can do this with a simple one liner:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 'A']

sum(filter(lambda i: isinstance(i, int), l1))
# prints 6
```

Or, if you need it inside a function:

```
def foo(l1):
    return sum(filter(lambda i: isinstance(i, int), l1))
```

Additionally, as noted in the comments, **don't** use names like `dict` and `list` for your variables; *they will shadow they build-in names for the dictionary (`dict`) and (`list`) types. You'll then need to explicitly `del dict, list` in order to use them as intended.

---

But, let me explain. What **[`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#filter)** does is here is:

**a)** It takes a function as its first argument:

```
# this function will return True if i is an int
# and false otherwise
lambda i: isinstance(i, int)
```

and then takes every element inside the list `l1` (second argument) and evaluates whether it is `True` or `False` based on the function.

**b)** Then, `filter` will essentially filter out any objects inside list `l1` that are not instances of `int` (i.e the function returns `False` for them). As a result, for a list like `[1, 2, 3, 'A']` filter is going to return `[1, 2, 3]` which will then be summed up by **[`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#sum)**.

Some Examples:

```
foo([1, 2, 3, 'A'])
# 6

foo([1, 2, 3])
# 6

foo([1, 2, 3, 'HELLO', 'WORLD'])
# 6
```

---

**Slight caveat:**

As is, this doesn't sum up `float` values, it drops them (and any other numeric types for that case). If you need that too, simply add the `float` type in the `lambda` function as so:

```
lambda i: isinstance(i, (int, float))
```

Now, your function sums floats too:

```
foo([1, 2, 3, 3.1,  'HELLO', 'WORLD'])
# 9.1
```

Add any other types as necessary in the `lambda` function to catch the cases that you need.

---

**A catch all case:**

As noted by **@Copperfield** you can check for objects that are instances of any number by utilizing the **[`numbers.Number`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/numbers.html#numbers.Number)** abstract base class in the **[`numbers`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/numbers.html)** module. This acts as a catch-all case for numeric values:

```
import numbers # must import
sum(filter(lambda i: isinstance(i, numbers.Number), l1))
```

**Simpler and a bit faster, too:**

Additionally, as noted by **@ShadowRanger**, and since [*`lambda` might not be the most comfortable construct for new users*](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/2emwwh/lambdas_are_confusing_me/), one could simply use *[a generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/)* (which is also faster) with `sum` to get the same exact result:

```
sum(val for val in l1 if isinstance(val, numbers.Number))
```

Comment: to include every numeric type without mention each one, you can use the corresponding [ABC](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html), for example `isinstance(item, numbers.Number)`

Comment: If you'd need a `lambda` to use `map`/`filter`, you may as well just use a generator expression (or list comp); you gain nothing in terms of either brevity or speed as soon as you resort to `lambda`s with `map`/`filter`.

Comment: The speed loss is neglidgible in this context but exists nontheless, I will edit my asnwer to include the generator based `sum` since it is also most explicit. The biggest loss here is probably due to `lambda` being an odd construct, and confusing people, especially new comers.

Answer (score 11):

The Pythonic way is to do a try/except. While you could do this in a one liner, I prefer to break things out a bit to see exactly what is happening.

```
val=0
for item in list:
    try:
        val+=int(item)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

If you want to include floating points, simply change the `int` to a `float`. Floating points are anything with a decimal, among others.

Comment: Not sure why you're being voted down. If this was anything more complicated than "Add the numbers" then this is ***exactly*** how to do it. The cheeky one-liner isn't better.

Comment: @AdamSmith: Sadly that is the case. Too many Python programmers like to try to cram as much as possible into a single line of code...

Comment: While I +1'd and in general do agree (as Adam said, in more complicated cases), *in this case* a `try-catch` is overkill. Additionally, you are wraping an `item` in an `int` call when it really shouldn't be necessary and, in order to generalize to encompass all Numbers, you'd probably do an `if isinstance` and drop the `try` altogether. `filter` is such a wonderful little function for exactly these things, can't see why you hatin' on it.

Comment: Downside to this approach: If the distinction between values to be kept and values to be dropped is based on type (`str` dropped, `int` kept), this code will fail if the input is `(1, 2, '3', '4')` by returning `10` instead of `3`; `int` will happily coerce numeric `str` to `int`.

Comment: The exercise said add all the _numbers_, not integers. So why not just change "val+=int(item)" to "val+=item"? That seems to me to fix the downside that's been mentioned - has the added virtue of then being exactly the solution I was about to post before seeing this, heh.

Answer (score 8):

```
sum([x for x in list if isinstance(x, (int, long, float))])
```

Comment: Best answer. Maybe using filter() would be more explicit.

Comment: `filter` is really only "better" when it gains you something on speed or brevity (and it only gains you speed when you can pass it a built-in function implemented in C on CPython). For something like this, a generator expression is best (same as current answer, but without the brackets that make a `list` comprehension, which means no intermediate `list`s being created and thrown away); it's no more or less explicit, and likely slightly faster.

Answer (score 4):

use filter and isinstance like this

```
>>> test = [1,2,3,4,5,6,"A","B"]
>>> sum(filter(lambda x:isinstance(x,int),test))
21
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def foo(list):
dict= "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN"
n=0
for i in range(0,len(list)-1):
    if str(list[i]) in dict:
        ""
    else:    
        n= n+list[i]
return n
print foo([1,2,3,4,5,6,"A","B"])
```

Comment: Why have you added your wrong code as an answer? You can delete it.

Comment: But it won't work if you have strings apart from A-N. E.g. Try "Z"

Comment: the way to say that you do nothing in a block of code is by using [`pass`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#pass). And in this case you can also use `if str(list[i]) not in dict` or `if not (str(list[i]) in dict)` and do the sum

Comment: @Copperfield: Actually, even if you put the `not` first, you still don't need additional parens; `not x in y` is already equivalent to (if slightly less readable to my mind) `x not in y`, no need for parens.

Answer (score 1):

```
def filtersum(L):
    if not L: return 0
    if not isinstance(L[0], int): return filtersum(L[1:])
    return L[0] + filtersum(L[1:])
```

Output:

```
In [28]: filtersum([1,2,3])
Out[28]: 6

In [29]: filtersum([1,'A', 2,3])
Out[29]: 6
```

Comment: why recursion? that is unnecessary overhead

Comment: OP wants answers for an exam - I imagine a professor would be quite impressed with this response from student in an intro to programming class

Comment: A code block alone does not provide a good answer. Please add explanations (why it solve the issue, where was the mistake, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum_intable(object_list):
    return sum(val for val in object_list
           if isinstance(val, (int, float)))
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?