# Trying to sum Python list

Tags: python, list, sum

this is my first post here, I am learning and practicing Python.

The problem is that anything I try to run after a for loop not running, so at the end I can’t get a total count. Maybe I should have created a function but now I need to know why this is happening, what have I done wrong?

```
lst = ["32.225.012", "US", "574.280", "17.997.267", "India", "201.187", "14.521.289", "Brazil", "398.185", "5.626.942", "France", "104.077", "4.751.026", "Turkey", "39.398", "4.732.981", "Russia", "107.547", "4.427.433", "United Kingdom", "127.734", "3.994.894", "Italy", "120.256", "3.504.799", "Spain", "77.943", "3.351.014", "Germany", "82.395", "2.905.172", "Argentina", "62.599", "2.824.626", "Colombia", "72.725", "2.776.927", "Poland", "66.533", "2.459.906", "Iran", "70.966", "2.333.126", "Mexico", "215.547", "2.102.130", "Ukraine", "45.211", "1.775.062", "Peru", "60.416", "1.657.035", "Indonesia", "45.116", "1.626.033", "Czechia", "29.141", "1.578.450", "South Africa", "54.285", "1.506.455", "Netherlands", "17.339", "1.210.077", "Canada", "24.105", "1.184.271", "Chile", "26.073", "1.051.868", "Iraq", "15.392", "1.051.779", "Romania", "27.833", "1.020.495", "Philippines", "17.031", "979.034", "Belgium", "24.104", "960.520", "Sweden", "14.000", "838.323", "Israel", "6.361", "835.563", "Portugal", "16.973", "810.231", "Pakistan", "17.530", "774.399", "Hungary", "27.172", "754.614", "Bangladesh", "11.305", "708.265", "Jordan", "8.754", "685.937", "Serbia", "6.312", "656.077", "Switzerland", "10.617", "614.510", "Austria", "10.152", "580.666", "Japan", "10.052", "524.241", "Lebanon", "7.224", "516.301", "United Arab Emirates", "1.580", "510.465", "Morocco", "9.015", "415.281", "Saudi Arabia", "6.935", "402.491", "Bulgaria", "16.278", "401.593", "Malaysia", "1.477", "381.180", "Slovakia", "11.611", "377.662", "Ecuador", "18.470", "366.709", "Kazakhstan", "3.326", "363.533", "Panama", "6.216", "355.924", "Belarus", "2.522", "340.493", "Greece", "10.242", "327.737", "Croatia", "7.001", "316.521", "Azerbaijan", "4.461", "312.699", "Nepal", "3.211","307.401", "Georgia", "4.077", "305.313", "Tunisia", "10.563", "300.258", "Bolivia", "12.885", "294.550", "West Bank and Gaza", "3.206", "271.814", "Paraguay", "6.094", "271.145", "Kuwait", "1.546", "265.819", "Dominican Republic", "3.467", "255.288", "Ethiopia", "3.639", "250.479", "Denmark", "2.482", "250.138", "Moldova", "5.780", "247.857", "Ireland", "4.896", "244.555", "Lithuania", "3.900", "243.167", "Costa Rica", "3.186", "238.421", "Slovenia", "4.236", "224.621", "Guatemala", "7.478", "224.517", "Egypt", "13.168", "214.872", "Armenia", "4.071", "208.356", "Honduras", "5.212", "204.289", "Qatar", "445","197.378", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "8.464", "193.721", "Venezuela", "2.082", "192.326", "Oman", "2.001","190.096", "Uruguay", "2.452", "176.701", "Libya", "3.019","174.659", "Bahrain", "632","164.912", "Nigeria", "2.063", "158.326", "Kenya", "2.688","151.569", "North Macedonia", "4.772", "142.790", "Burma", "3.209","130.859", "Albania", "2.386", "121.580", "Algeria", "3.234", "121.232", "Estonia", "1.148", "120.673", "Korea. South", "1.821", "117.099", "Latvia", "2.118", "111.915", "Norway", "753","104.953", "Sri Lanka", "661", "104.512", "Cuba", "614","103.638", "Kosovo", "2.134", "102.426", "China", "4.845","97.080", "Montenegro", "1.485", "94.599", "Kyrgyzstan", "1.592", "92.513", "Ghana", "779","91.484", "Zambia", "1.249","90.008", "Uzbekistan", "646", "86.405", "Finland", "908","69.804", "Mozambique", "814", "68.922", "El Salvador", "2.117", "66.826", "Luxembourg", "792", "65.998", "Cameroon", "991","63.720", "Cyprus", "303","61.699", "Thailand", "178","61.086", "Singapore", "30","59.370", "Afghanistan", "2.611", "48.177", "Namibia", "638","46.600", "Botswana", "702","45.885", "Cote d'Ivoire", "285", "45.292", "Jamaica", "770","41.766", "Uganda", "341","40.249", "Senegal", "1.107", "38.191", "Zimbabwe", "1.565", "36.510", "Madagascar", "631", "34.052", "Malawi", "1.147","33.944", "Sudan", "2.349","33.608", "Mongolia", "97","30.249", "Malta", "413","29.768", "Congo Kinshasa", "763", "29.749", "Australia", "910", "29.052", "Maldives", "72","25.942", "Angola", "587","24.888", "Rwanda", "332","23.181", "Cabo Verde", "213", "22.568", "Gabon", "138","22.513", "Syria", "1.572","22.087", "Guinea", "141","18.452", "Eswatini", "671","18.314", "Mauritania", "455", "13.915", "Somalia", "713","13.780", "Mali", "477","13.308", "Tajikistan", "90", "13.286", "Burkina Faso", "157", "13.148", "Andorra", "125","13.017", "Haiti", "254","12.963", "Guyana", "293","12.898", "Togo", "122","12.631", "Belize", "322","11.761", "Cambodia", "88","10.986", "Djibouti", "142","10.915", "Papua New Guinea", "107", "10.730", "Lesotho", "316","10.678", "Congo Brazzaville", "144", "10.553", "South Sudan", "114", "10.220", "Bahamas", "198","10.170", "Trinidad and Tobago", "163", "10.157", "Suriname", "201","7.821", "Benin", "99","7.559", "Equatorial Guinea", "107", "6.898", "Nicaragua", "182","6.456", "Iceland", "29","6.359", "Central African Republic", "87", "6.220", "Yemen", "1.207","5.882", "Gambia", "174","5.354", "Seychelles", "26","5.220", "Niger", "191","5.059", "San Marino", "90","4.789", "Chad", "170","4.508", "Saint Lucia", "74", "4.049", "Sierra Leone", "79", "3.941", "Burundi", "6","3.833", "Comoros", "146","3.831", "Barbados", "44","3.731", "Guinea-Bissau", "67", "3.659", "Eritrea", "10","2.908", "Liechtenstein", "57", "2.865", "Vietnam", "35","2.610", "New Zealand", "26", "2.447", "Monaco", "32","2.301", "Sao Tome and Principe", "35", "2.124", "Timor-Leste", "3","2.099", "Liberia", "85","1.850", "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", "11", "1.232", "Antigua and Barbuda", "32", "1.207", "Mauritius", "17","1.116", "Taiwan", "12","1.059", "Bhutan", "1","712", "Diamond Princess", "13", "604", "Laos", "0","509", "Tanzania", "21","224", "Brunei", "3","173", "Dominica", "0","159", "Grenada", "1","111", "Fiji", "2","44", "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "0", "27", "Holy See", "0","20", "Solomon Islands", "0", "9", "MS Zaandam", "2","4", "Marshall Islands", "0", "4", "Vanuatu", "1","3", "Samoa", "0","1", "Micronesia", "0"]
```

```
countryIndex = 1
 casesIndex = 0
 deathsIndex = 2

 countries = []
 cases = []
 deaths = []

for item in lst:
    print(f"Country: {lst[countryIndex]}")
    print(f"Cases: {lst[casesIndex]}")
    print(f"Deaths: {lst[deathsIndex]}")
    print("")

    countryToAppend = lst[countryIndex]
    casesToAppend = lst[casesIndex]
    deathsToAppend = lst[deathsIndex]

    countries.append(countryToAppend)
    cases.append(casesToAppend)
    deaths.append(deathsToAppend)

    countryIndex += 3
    casesIndex += 3
    deathsIndex += 3


total = sum(deaths)
print(f"Total deaths: {total}")
```

Comment: Please post your code, so we can understand what's wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [summing only the numbers contained in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34728246/summing-only-the-numbers-contained-in-a-list)

Comment: The question title says sum python list, but the list contents are strings. Are you trying to concatenate strings? Then you ask for count... that would be len(list). Also, note list is a keyword in python, so use a_list or a non keyword.

Comment: Here’s the rest of the code, had to indent all properly before posting it, sorry for the delay.

Comment: I’d like to use len() to count how many countries in the countries list

Comment: And the other two lists “cases” and “deaths” I want to sum each list to get totals. About the list keyword, I’m going to change it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

On top of the suggestion to replace the name of the data set to not use the reserved word list, my recommendation would be to leverage the ability to skip in the builtin `range` in an example like so:

```
# Lists to store data
countries = []
total_cases = []
total_deaths = []

# Iterate over thje range of the data skipping 3 at a time: 0, 3, ...
for x in range(0, len(data), 3):
    # Parse out the cases a deaths to ints
    cases = int(data[x].replace('.', ''))
    deaths = int(data[x+2].replace('.', ''))
    
    # We can just extract the country label
    country_label = data[x+1]
    
    countries.append(country_label)
    total_cases.append(cases)
    total_deaths.append(deaths)
    
# Get the desired sums
sum_cases = sum(total_cases)
sum_deaths = sum(total_deaths)

print(f"The total cases: {sum_cases}")
print(f"The total deaths: {sum_deaths}")
```

Above I renamed your dataset to be `data` and was able to sum up each list.

Comment: Very good, thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

```
sum = 0 
for i in range(2,len(l),3): # l is your list of data , 
    sum = sum+int(l[i].replace('.','')) # here I removed the point between numbers ex: 574.280 --> 574280
print(sum)

#output : 3145239
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems a little complex to me yet.

Comment: if it's not clear, i can explain more